# Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    FileNumber, 
    dbo.GetLocalDateTimeFunc(SentDate) AS SentDate 
INTO #tmp1
FROM FileMain f 
JOIN FileActions fa ON f.FileID = fa.FileID
WHERE ActionDefID = 15 AND SentDate IS NOT NULL

SELECT 
    FileNumber, 
    dbo.GetLocalDateTimeFunc(ReceivedDate) AS ReceivedDate 
INTO #tmp2
FROM FileMain f 
JOIN FileActions fa ON f.FileID = fa.FileID
WHERE ActionDefID = 23 AND ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.Name AS Company, fm.FileNumber, pc.Name as Client, 
    p.State, c.County, t1.SentDate, t2.ReceivedDate,
(SELECT sum(case    
        when dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, t1.SentDate), 0) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, t2.ReceivedDate), 0) then
            datediff(second, t1.SentDate, t2.ReceivedDate)
        when [DATE] = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, t1.SentDate), 0) then
            case    
            when t1.SentDate > [DATE] + begin_time then datediff(second, t1.SentDate, [DATE] + end_time)
            else duration
            end
        when [DATE] = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, t2.ReceivedDate), 0) then
            case    
            when t2.ReceivedDate    <  [DATE] + end_time then datediff(second, [DATE] + begin_time, t2.ReceivedDate)
            else duration
            end
        else duration
        end
          ) 
        / 60.0 / 60.0
    FROM F_TABLE_DATE(t1.SentDate, t2.ReceivedDate) d 
    INNER JOIN Unisource_Calendar c ON d.WEEKDAY_NAME_LONG = c.day_name)
FROM Office o
JOIN PartnerCompany pc ON o.OfficeID = pc.OfficeID
JOIN FileMain fm ON o.OfficeID = fm.OfficeID AND pc.PartnerCompanyID = fm.ClientID
JOIN Property p ON p.FileID = fm.FileID
JOIN County c ON p.CountyID = c.CountyID
JOIN FileActions fa ON fm.FileID = fa.FileID
JOIN #tmp1 t1 ON t1.FileNumber = fm.FileNumber
JOIN #tmp2 t2 ON t2.FileNumber = fm.FileNumber
WHERE p.State IN ('AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 'GA', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NJ', 'NV', 'NH', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'TN', 'TX', 'VA', 'WV', 'WI')
ORDER BY SentDate, FileNumber DESC
```

I'm getting the following error on my subquery:

> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Or if someone has a function that can calculate datetime differences while excluding business hours and weekends that would help also. Thanks!

Comment: You may try to convert that `(SELECT SUM() ...)` subquery to an `OUTER APPLY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to simplify your code using CTEs for a start (enumeration of ALL tables distracts to give a precise statement). Also you should try your aggregate SUM function as a part of PARTITION by expression. This would probably help to avoid the problem you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with CTE's. Actually, I'm not an advanced SQL Developer either, as you can see from my code. Do you have any pointers for me in regards to creating a CTE?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can glean, the table function F_Table_Date is returning DATE or DATETIME rows for each day between the two parameters, and the UnisourceCalendar Is likely a list of work days (to allot for holidays as you mentioned). If this is the case, and UnisourceCalendar also returns a DATE or DATETIME column, consider this for your subquery:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) * 60*60*24)
  + (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM UnisourceCalendar
     WHERE [DATE] = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.SentDate+1,112) AS DATETIME)
    )*DATEDIFF(SS,t1.SentDate,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.SentDate+1,112) AS DATETIME))
  + (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM UnisourceCalendar
     WHERE [DATE] = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,t1.SentDate+1,112) AS DATETIME)
    )*DATEDIFF(SS,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.ReceivedDate,112) AS DATETIME),t2.ReceivedDate)
FROM UnisourceCalendar C
WHERE C.[DATE] > t1.SentDate AND C.[DATE] < t2.ReceivedDate
GROUP BY t1.SentDate, t2.ReceivedDate
```

What's at Play here:

1. Presuming 1 row per business day from UnisourceCalendar, any other join is superfluous.
2. A count is all that's needed, then.
3. The datediff of a converted/cast value of one date against itself using style 112 strips the time out and is recast as midnight, thus allowing us to get the seconds to next midnight from the sent date, and from the previous midnight of the received date, but only if each date is in the unisource calendar (mulitply by count, if 0, then no seconds added, if 1, then add the extra seconds).
4. Output is presuming that you will be dividing the results down to hours outside the subquery as you are.

Complicated? Sure, but it should output the results you're looking for in relatively short order.